# Laravel - Post request empty fields

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I'm using `Laravel` with `Nginx`, `PHP 7.1` and `Ubuntu 18`.

I have a login form as follows:

Login.blade.php:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'LoginController@login'],['class' => 'form'])!!}
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">{{__("Login to your account")}}</h2>
      {!! Form::text('timezone', null,
    array('style'=>'display:none',
      'class'=>'form-control',
      'id'=>'timezone',
      'placeholder'=>__('timezone'))) !!}

      {!! Form::text('pushToken', null,
    array('style'=>'display:none',
      'class'=>'form-control',
      'id'=>'pushToken',
      'placeholder'=>__('Token'))) !!}
   {!! Form::text('email', null,
    array('required',
      'class'=>'form-control',
      'placeholder'=>__('Email'))) !!}
   {!! Form::password('password',
    array('required','placeholder' => __('Password'))) !!}
    {!! Form::checkbox('remember_me', null, null, array(
    'class'=>'checkbox',
    'style'=>'width: fit-content; display: inline-block'
    ))!!}{{__("Remember Me")}}

   {!! Form::Submit(__('Login'), null,
    array(
      'class'=>'form-control'
      )) !!}

      {!! Form::close() !!}
```

In my controller when I try to check the values of `email` and `password`, they are always empty. Knowing that when I test on `ubuntu 16.04` everything is fine

Controller Code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Request as Req;
use Session;
use Cookie;
use Config;
use Redirect;
class LoginController extends Controller
{


    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $email = Req::input('email');
        $password = Req::input('password');
        echo $email;
}}
```

Composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "mariuzzo/laravel-js-localization": "^1.4",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.25",
        "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.0"
    },
```

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya added composer.json

Comment: Can you post all the code from your controller please. I have a feeling you are calling request statically and not through the request argument of the controller method

Comment: Maybe it's something in php.ini settings

Comment: @thisiskelvin added whole controller

Comment: @Hussein what something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what went wrong 
in my .env

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.production.tld
```

removed that line and everything is now fine

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `Request` passed as an argument to the `login()` method, and not the request which you have aliased at the top of the controller class.

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        echo $email;
  }
```

Comment: @mustafabarakat Let me know if this works with the edit

Comment: it's empty too, i don't think that's the issue because it's working when using older version of ubuntu

Comment: @mustafabarakat Have you tried to `dd($request->all())` and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Controller methods always receives a parameter `Request`. Try this:

```
public function methodInYourController(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');
}
```

Comment: can i see output of $_REQUEST?

Answer (score 1):

Many times it happens that there are problems in the .htaccess file.

By default laravel comes with a ModRewrite rule that redirects everything that is not a file, or folders, to index.php, but ami never ends up working well ... so I correct it every time I do a project.
I change the syntax a little bit to capture everything but with (. *) And **very important to re-transmit the QueryString of the GET requests is the keyword "QSA"** that I add after "L" (last rule)

in my case I leave the rule like this:

```
# Handle Front Controller ...
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-D
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F
     RewriteRule ^(.*) $ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I hope this helps someone!